# Renew a Long-Lived token used at server side with an Angular application and FB SDK

Tags: angularjs, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-access-token

My context: 
An AngularJS application using the Javascript Facebook SDK, and my distinct server (REST APIs).

Workflow:
User is logged in the client through the FB SDK using the method `FB.login(callback)`.
This later gives a short-lived token that is then sent to the server in order to transform it to a long-lived token.

I'm interested in the mechanism of refreshing the long-lived token after 60 days.

So, reading the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#refreshtokens), we found this:

> Even the long-lived access token will eventually expire. At any point,
>   **you can generate a new long-lived token by sending the person back to
>   the login flow used by your web app** - note that the person will not
>   actually need to login again, they have already authorized your app,
>   so they will immediately redirect back to your app from the login flow
>   with a refreshed token - how this appears to the person will vary
>   based on the type of login flow that you are using, for example if you
>   are using the JavaScript SDK, this will take place in the background,
>   if you are using a server-side flow, the browser will quickly redirect
>   to the Login Dialog and then automatically and immediately back to
>   your app again.

If I interpret it well, when user is ALREADY logged in through `FB.login(callback)`, a simple redirect to the Angular Application's login flow would allow to get a new short-lived token.
I imagine that the `FB.login` is immediately run anew in this case, without user interaction, as written.

I want to test it simply, so what I've done is:

- Logged in into the application through `FB.login(callback)`.
- Clicked on a dummy link making a simple redirect with:  `window.location.replace('/');`

My application being a single page application, every URL should be considered as the authentication page.

But the `FB.login` isn't run in the background, as I expected from the doc.

What would be the reason?
Does it work only when the domain making the redirect is distinct from the client? (I just can't test this case right now)

Did I misinterpret the doc?

Comment: If you want to check the user’s authentication status in the background, use `FB.getLoginStatus`.

Comment: Yes I know, thanks. But I don't want to check, I want to understand the mechanism ;)

Comment: Well then what do you actually want to know here? `FB.login` tries to open a popup, so it can’t actually be “in the background”. If the user is already authenticated and no new permissions are asked for, then that popup will close itself again straight away, without showing anything to the user. But automatic calls to `FB.login` might get caught in the browser’s popup blocker, which is why the recommendation is to only call that method on explicit user interaction (like a click).

Comment: @CBroe "the recommendation is to only call that method on explicit user interaction (like a click)." => You touch the point! That's the main idea of my question. So I rephrase my question:  Bob is logging in the app through `FB.login`. Its callback calls a process aiming to transform the short into a long-lived token. Then after 60 days, Bob calls this REST API:  `mydomain.com/doSomething`. This method needs a valid long-lived token to ensure its goal, but it's invalid. I imagine a redirect should be sent to the client app, and that is where I'm confused.. what happens and how?

Comment: If you just embed the JS SDK, it will always automatically see to it that you have a valid short-lived user access token available on the client side.

Comment: @CBroe May you detail the steps? It really troubles me.. Just after the "redirect" to the app from the server. How does the SDK behave when it grabs the redirect. How does it end up to complete successfully the `doSomething` call without any user interaction?

Comment: _“How does the SDK behave when it grabs the redirect”_ – that doesn’t even make sense, the client-side JS SDK doesn’t “grab” any redirects. You need to show a page on the client, that embeds the JS SDK. That will get you a fresh, short-lived user access token (assuming the user is already logged in to Facebook in the browser, otherwise they will have to do that first). What you do with that token then, is up to you. (So you will probably want to send it to the server, to create a new extended token.)

Comment: @CBroe Oh ok, that was really what I thought beforewards. some people told me all what I stated here..probably wrong so. So the user would need to manually recall `doSomething` API in the end. Making more sense obviously. I would just need a way to detect when a short-lived token must be transformed to long-lived token in this typical case of expiration. Perhaps the best idea is to pass a param or call specific url at the client side when redirecting, in order to trigger the short-lived token transformation at server side.